# Retrieve Plain text from string while retrieving from db itself.(Need to avoid all fonts and styles)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angular, asp.net-core

I am having "Expected Outstanding On Economical End Date" in my db(this is copy pasted with some font).
But when I retrieve it on html page its showing as below.

```
 <label class="control-label table_cell" >
                                <span>Expected Outstanding&nbsp;On&nbsp;Economical End Date</span>
                            </label>
```

But when I manually updated it with plane text it is coming properly.

```
<label class="control-label table_cell" `enter code here`>
                            <span>Expected Outstanding On Economical End Date</span>
                        </label>
```

How to convert this to plane text with out any font and styles while retrieving from the db?

Comment: &nbsp; means non-breaking space, it is used to leave a space ' ' without breaking line while word wrapping, if you're getting this from the db, then the data you've stored in the db is actually `Expected Outstanding&nbsp;On&nbsp;Economical End Date` and not `Expected Outstanding On Economical End Date` Please check and revert if wrong

Comment: I have a bunch of data like this in db. Need to avoid this while retrieving .. any hope?

Answer (score 0):

As @kowsikbabu said, `&nbsp;` is an HTML entity for the non-breaking space character. It is a special character, which looks like a space when rendered, but does not allow a break like a space would when wrapping.

I'm not sure how it ended up in your data in the first place. That is probably the first place you should look. However, whatever means you're using to update the value later, understands the HTML entity and is treating it as a space thereafter when data gets submitted. So, after your update, the `&nbsp;` entities have literally been replaced with normal spaces.

Now when you print it in the view, Razor actually escapes HTML by default to prevent script injection and other nasty exploits of the sort. In other words, what *actually* gets print in the source is:

```
Expected Outstanding&amp;nbsp;On&amp;nbsp;Economical End Date
```

The `&amp;` HTML entity corresponds to the `&` character, which is why when *rendered* by the browser you end up with:

```
Expected Outstanding&nbsp;On&nbsp;Economical End Date
```

To prevent Razor doing this, you can use `@Html.Raw(Model.Property)`, which will then print the string unescaped, allowing the `&nbsp;` characters to come through in the source unmolested, which will then allow the browser to render them properly as spaces.

Long and short, if you can't control HTML entities ending up in the value, then use `@Html.Raw` to display the value and you'll be fine. Otherwise, if you don't want the value to actually allow HTML, then you need to figure out why its getting in there in the first place and fix that.

Comment: Not the razor .. I am using plain HTML with angular